# Algorithm for clustering Tweets based on geo radius

Tags: java, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster tweets based on a specified geo-radius like (10 meters). If for example I specify 10 meters radius, then I want all tweets that are within 10 meters to be in one cluster.

A simple algorithm could be to calculate the distance between each tweet and each other tweets, but that would be very computationally expensive. Are there better algorithms to do this?

Comment: You should correct your question. As is, it has no solution: Imagine points A,B,C, that are on the line, with 6 m intervals. Should we put them into clusters as {AB,C}, or {A, BC}, or {ABC}?

Comment: You want to cluster your data so you can lookup faster.

Maybe this idea can help you.
http://kunuk.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/k-nearest-neighbor-in-2d-dimension-space/ 

The implementation has the option to set a max-distance and you can set k to a high value.
This will give you tweets within x distance from any selected tweet in much faster running time compared to the naive compare-all-distances approach.

Comment: Look up **indexes**. They can accelerate distance queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your tweets in a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). This makes it quite easy to find tweets near by without looking at all tweeds and their location. 
The quadtree does not directly deliver the distance (because it is based on a [Manhatten-distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) but it gives you near by tweets, for which you can calculate the precise distance afterwards afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only in computation of distances:

1. remember: you should never count distances if you need them for comparison only. Use their squares instead.

   Do not compare:

   sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2) against 10

   compare instead

   (x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2 against 100

   It takes GREATLY less time.
2. The other improvement can be reached if you simply compare coordinates before comparing squares of distances. If abs(x1-x2)>1, you needn't that pair anymore. (It is the Manchattan distance MrSmith is speaking about)
3. I don't know how you work with your points, but if their set is stable, you could make two arrays of them, and in each one order them according to one of the coordinates. After that you need to check only these points that are close to the source one in both arrays.

Comment: Also, maybe you do not necessarily need to use a radius and not necessarily in meters. Then you can just do a DB query saying: lat < LAT + d_lat && lat > LAT - d_lat && lon < LON + d_lon && lon > LON - d_lon LIMIT x; d_lon and d_lat can be calculated based on your position.

Comment: saving the `sqrt` only saves a little, on fairly small data sets. Using actual index structures saves an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse If the data set is dynamic, the index structure support costs times more than straight comparing all elements. On the other hand, squares comparison is an UNIVERSAL rule. It is ALWAYS better.

Comment: You will be surprised how often - even for dynamic data - index structures pay off very well. When implemented well, which is where many people fail. The savings by saving the `sqrt` may easily be eaten up by cache issues etc. - computing the sqrt for a value already in the CPU register takes little time, probably less than fetching the next one from main memory.

Comment: Surely. I have even described an indexed structure in the third point - not using the term, but the explanation how it works. But is he is comparing distances instead of squares, the first change should be to compare squares instead. It works always and is very simple.

Comment: To count on sqrt argument being in cache? Are you serious? We are talking about floats, don't forget. And if they are integers, the effect of change to squares is even greater.